# Assigning workbook and worksheet properly VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have searched for this issue already, but all the examples are way too complicated.
I just cannot use "Set workbook" and "Set worksheets" object. I will get error 1004: Object-defined error.

I would like to read path from the destination file sheet "Path": C:\Users\Holger\Documents\VBA\WB_data.xlsx

Please someone help.

```
Sub Get_numbers()

'I have got 2 sheets
Dim WB_dest As Workbook
Dim WB_data As Workbook

'I need 3 worksheets
Dim path_sheet As Worksheet
Dim dest_sheet As Worksheet
Dim data_sheet As Worksheet

'Data worksheet's path
Dim path As String

'Counter
Dim i As Byte

'I run this sub from destination file sheet "PATH" which is already open
Set WB_dest = ThisWorkbook
Set path_sheet = WB_dest.Worksheets("Path")
Set dest_sheet = WB_dest.Worksheets("TO")

'I set worksheet from the Excel taht I do not need to open, just reading
Set WB_data = Workbooks.Open(path)
Set data_sheet = WB_data.Worksheets("FROM")

'Data sheet contains three numbers in the first column
'and destination sheet also contains only three numbers in the first coulm
'I would like to add data_sheet numbers after dest_sheet numbers
For i = 4 To 6
    dest_sheet.Cells(i, 1) = data_sheet(i, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: You never define the variable `path` so when you try to open a workbook, it can't find a path of `null`

Comment: What is `data_sheet(i, 1)` supposed to be? `data_sheet` is a worksheet. What's the `(i,1)` supposed to be referencing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub Get_numbers()

'I have got 2 sheets
Dim WB_dest As Workbook
Dim WB_data As Workbook

'I need 3 worksheets
Dim path_sheet As Worksheet
Dim dest_sheet As Worksheet
Dim data_sheet As Worksheet

'Data worksheet's path
Dim path As String

'Counter
Dim i As Byte

path = "C:\Users\Holger\Documents\VBA\WB_data.xlsx"

'I run this sub from destination file sheet "PATH" which is already open
Set WB_dest = ThisWorkbook
Set path_sheet = WB_dest.Worksheets("Path")
Set dest_sheet = WB_dest.Worksheets("TO")

'I set worksheet from the Excel taht I do not need to open, just reading
Set WB_data = Workbooks.Open(path)
Set data_sheet = WB_data.Worksheets("FROM")

'Data sheet contains three numbers in the first column
'and destination sheet also contains only three numbers in the first coulm
'I would like to add data_sheet numbers after dest_sheet numbers

data_sheet.Range("A4:A6").Copy
dest_sheet.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'For i = 4 To 6
'    dest_sheet.Cells(i, 1) = data_sheet(i, 1)
'Next i

End Sub
```